# Android SDKs eating up my hard drive; what can I safely delete?

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova-plugins, android-sdk-manager

My app targets Android 4.4 and up.  But I have SDKs from like 14-25 installed via the Studio SDK Manager.  I don't use the emulator except on rare occasions - but when I do its typically for 4.4 & 5x.  But collectively Android Studio is taking up over 100Gb of storage on my system...I need to reduce its size (big time)

What can I delete that allows me to still target 4.4 and everything newer?

This question has been asked a multitude of times but everything I researched did not provide a clear answer.

1. If I delete 14-24, and build my app with just SDK 25, can my app still support Android 4.4?  Or do I need to hold on to specific SDKs so that my app will still support all Android versions 4.4 and higher?  Please be specific, too many vague answers out there.
2. My app is a cordova/ionic app - many plugins references specific versions of SDKs - typically based on when the plugin was last updated.  But quite often these plugins are tested with SDK 22, or SDK 21 (mainly because the author has never bothered to update/maintain the plugin - but it still works) - will those plugins still work if SDKs 14-24 are deleted and only SDK 25 is installed?
3. As mentioned, I occasionally need the emulator for specific system-images; in lieu of question #1 - if I want to try spin up Android 4.4 emulator do I also need to keep specific SDKs to support those system-images.
4. Using the Android Studio SDK Manager - does removing specific SDKs via the manager also delete things from my hard drive?  I would think it would, but I read some other blogs where people were manually having to delete things.

Answer (score 0):

1. the Build procedure depends of BuildTools and Android SDK. If you set "minSdkVersion: 10" and "targetSdkVersion: 27" then YOU SHOULD manage all code differences between all versions. There are two possibilities: **(A)** older method/class is not more available on newer SDK: then the bulld procedure will fail because you cannot call/use them directly but only via Reflection **(B)** newer method/class is not present in the older SDK: then the build procedure ends fine but your App will crash when THAT method/class is used if you don't manage that specific case using "*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.xxxx)...*"
2. it depends of what kind of plugin they are. Are they AAR file? Are they an editable project that you could join/add to yours? are them external libraries? AAR files and .SO libraries are already compiled so they doesn't need any other/external file or development tool.
3. Emulator runs using its own "System OS" files, so all the development stuff is unuseful for it. You can run an Emulator even without having never installed a development tool (Android Studio or other things)
4. Removing items from the Manager should remove even its files, but in some case there could be a bug and nothing (or just partially) is deleted. But you can check your drive storage free space if it is increased.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a tool that can analyze my app that will help me figure out the minimum SDK I need to prevent it from crashing?  An example, maybe an older phone running KitKat 4.4 can run my app even if the SDK 19 was removed from the project build (via Studio SDK Manager) because there is nothing in my app that specifically needs SDK 19 features.  I would still set the minSdkVersion for my app to be `19` - but that's just the users phone.

Comment: I don't think there is a software/App that do what you need, maybe because it's quite not possible (think about Reflection or external .SO libraries: how that tool could "read" these two things?)